# ember - loading model data in route for power sort?

Tags: ember.js, model

I have a very simple set up right now. I have a book model that has a name and author. I'm trying to create a simple form that will create a new book. For the author I'm using power select to load the authors from the author model. The form set up looks like this:

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=model.title placeholder="Title"}}<br>

    {{#power-select class="select"
        selected=model.author
        options=authors
        onchange=(action (mut model.author)) as |author|}}
        {{author.name}}
    {{/power-select}}

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

However I'm having trouble setting up the route to get this working. So far no authors show up in the select, even though there are authors stored in my database. My route looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return this.store.createRecord('book');
    },
    actions: {
        save() {
            this.modelFor(this.routeName).save();
        }
    },

    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    authors: Ember.computed({
        get() {
            return this.get('store').findAll('author');
        }
    }).readOnly()
});
```

First of all, how should I properly load data from the author model in the route for the books/new route? Secondly, should I be doing this in the route? From what I have read, and what people have told me, loading model data should be done in the route.

Answer (score 0):

Move `authors` property to corresponding controller.

Also you don't need to add `readonly`.

So in controller :

```
  authors: Ember.computed(function(){
                return this.get('store').findAll('author');        
})
```

And for loading model in route. Yes you should load that model which is to be a resource manipulating, in  route. So now you're doing it right.

Comment: I see, so use the route for loading model data for that route. But if you want to load data from other models, then use the controller?

Comment: @PCR No. You can load `authors` in route `model` hook by using `Ember.RSVP.hash` too. But `authors` is not a resource which your route dealing with. I mean route is responsible for managing a resouce (in your case book). And authors is just a collection for a select box and not modified in your form. I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

1) Using `Ember.RSVP.hash` inside route model hook

> your route file-> I assume books/new.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            newBook : this.store.createRecord('book'),
            authors : this.store.findAll('author')          
        });
    },
    actions: {
        save() {
            this.modelFor(this.routeName).newBook.save(); 
        }
    }    
});
```

and inside template you can access `authors` by using `model.authors`. and `title` by using `model.newBook.title`

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
    {{input value=model.newBook.title placeholder="Title"}}<br>

    {{#power-select class="select"
        selected=model.newBook.author
        options=model.authors
        onchange=(action (mut model.newBook.author)) as |author|}}
        {{author.name}}
    {{/power-select}}

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

2) Like ebrahim suggested, you can have the below code in required controller,

```
authors: Ember.computed(function(){
           return this.store.findAll('author');        
})
```

3)As author model data is going to be shared data model for authors,books,books.new routes. so you can keep it in service and access it from all the required routes.

> authors-service.js -> In service

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store:Ember.inject.service(),
  authors: undefined,
  init(){
   this._super(...arguments);
   this.get('store').findAll('author', { reload: true }).then(function(results){
        this.set('authors',results); //As this is going to be  Ember.enumerables, you can iterate and get the data.
    });
 }
});
```

You can access `authors` from `authors-service.js` in any where by injecting it
`authorsService:Ember.inject.service()`. I guess in your case, you need to create controller `books/new.js` for `books/new.hbs` template,

> books/new.js  -> controller file

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({  
  authorsService:Ember.inject.service(),
  authors: Ember.computed.alias('authorsService.authors');
});
```

Inside books/new.hbs template you can access `authors` property.

Comment: Hey I tried using `this.modelFor(this.routeName).get('newBook').save(); ` in my route file, however in my console it gives me the error `this.modelFor(...).get is not a function`

Comment: Oh sorry, you can access like this.modelFor(this.routeName).newBook.save(). since RSVP hash is not returning Ember object.. i updated my answer